# Не/анонимно ― вместе или раздельно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, слитно-раздельно, частица-не, наречия

Вместе или раздельно пишется **не/анонимно?**

Answer (score 1):

Стандартные правила написания *"не"* с наречиями действуют и в этом случае.

*"Запись опубликована не анонимно, а с указанием имени автора"*. Противопоставление - *"не X, а Y"*.

*"Запись опубликована неанонимно, в конце указано имя автора"*. При этом вторую часть предложения можно опустить.

Заранее отметаю аргументы на тему [возможного] отсутствия в словаре наречия "неанонимно" и/или прилагательного "неанонимный". Не все правильно образованные слова есть в словарях.

Для сравнения:

*"Мне было не хорошо, а плохо"*.

*"Мне было нехорошо, меня подташнивало"*.

Просто нет очевидного антонима к слову "анонимно" (в отличие от "хорошо" - "плохо"), поэтому и неясность возникает.

Но вообще да, "неанонимно" звучит немного коряво. Если есть возможность, лучше перефразировать: *"Запись не была опубликована анонимно"*.

Comment: *Запись опубликована неанонимно, в конце указано имя автора* - здесь запросто возможно раздельное написание. Более того, я бы именно её и предпочел в нейтральном стиле, скорее слитное написание вызывает вопросы, что это за качество такое "неанонимность".

Answer (score 1):

Возможны оба варианта, причем для раздельного написания не требуется обязательного противопоставления. Выбор авторский, также зависит от структуры предложения.

**Слитно (утверждение)**

Ответьте подробно, **неанонимно**, обязательно с карточкой и только заказным письмом, ― иначе не отвечу. [Объявления (1914.12.27). Однородные отношения с другими обстоятельствами.

Я знаю несколько девушек, которые с удовольствием примут участие, **даже неанонимно**. Поверьте, я сама далека от идеала, и провоцировать люблю, и гадость могу написать (в глаза и **неанонимно**).

**Раздельно (отрицание)**

Дай мне руку и будь моей женой, миловидная, изящная, развитая, музыкальная барышня, без прошлого и со средствами от 25 тысяч. Прошу карточку и писать **не анонимно**. Обоюдная тайна. [неизвестный. Объявления (1908.11.22)

Или вы меня оскорбляете? А **не анонимно** ― слабо?

Comment: Наверно все-таки не от "структуры", а от значения, смысла и вообще контекста? Т. е. семантики? Понимаете, в ваших примерах на слитное написание ничто не мешает написать раздельно, передавая именно отрицание, разве структура от того поменяется?

Answer (score 1):

По поводу возможности обоих написаний в зависимости от смысла вам уже довольно много понаписали.

Есть еще одно доброе правило, точнее - совет. Если сомневаешься, пиши раздельно. Случаи, когда подобные образования однозначно требуют слитного написания крайне редки и как правило не вызывают вопросов (обычно это когда слово без "не" просто не употребляется). Во всех остальных случаях раздельное написание как минимум допустимо.